# Testing Coroutines runBlockingTest time

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Using this [manual](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/) to test Coroutines using `runBlockingTest`.

I encountered some issues.

> If the coroutine created by launch or async calls delay then the
>   runBlockingTest will not auto-progress time right away. This allows
>   tests to observe the interaction of multiple coroutines with different
>   delays.

```
@Test
fun testFooWithLaunchAndDelay() = runBlockingTest {
    foo()
    // the coroutine launched by foo has not completed here, it is suspended waiting for delay(1_000)
    advanceTimeBy(1_000) // progress time, this will cause the delay to resume
    // the coroutine launched by foo has completed here
    // ...
}

suspend fun CoroutineScope.foo() {
    launch {
        println(1)   // executes eagerly when foo() is called due to runBlockingTest
        delay(1_000) // suspends until time is advanced by at least 1_000
        println(2)   // executes after advanceTimeBy(1_000)
    }
}
```

Even if i comment out `advanceTimeBy(1_000)` time clock progress instantly. Advancing less than delay time not working either.

> Time control can be used to test timeout code. To do so, ensure that
>   the function under test is suspended inside a withTimeout block and
>   advance time until the timeout is triggered.

```
@Test(expected = TimeoutCancellationException::class)
fun testFooWithTimeout() = runBlockingTest {
    val uncompleted = CompletableDeferred<Foo>() // this Deferred<Foo> will never complete
    foo(uncompleted)
    advanceTimeBy(1_000) // advance time, which will cause the timeout to throw an exception
    // ...
}

fun CoroutineScope.foo(resultDeferred: Deferred<Foo>) {
    launch {
        withTimeout(1_000) {
            resultDeferred.await() // await() will suspend forever waiting for uncompleted
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This test does not throw `TimeoutCancellationException` and fails.

Comment: did you find the reason for that behaviour?