# Is it possible to spy on suspend Android Room DAO functions with MockK

Tags: android, android-room, junit4, mockk

I am investigation the MockK library with my Android JUnit tests

```
testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:1.10.0"
```

I have an issue when attempting to spyk on suspend functions

heres my Junit test

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@FlowPreview
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class BackOffCriteriaDaoTest : BaseTest() {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private lateinit var dao: BackoffCriteriaDAO

        @Test
        fun backOffCriteria() = runBlocking {
            dao = spyk(myRoomDatabase.backoffCriteriaDAO())
            assertNotNull(dao.getBackoffCriteria())
            assertEquals(backOffCriteriaDO, dao.getBackoffCriteria())
            dao.delete()
    
            coVerify {
                myRoomDatabase.backoffCriteriaDAO()
                dao.reset()
            }
        }
    }
```

This test throws an java.lang.AssertionError at `dao.reset()` as follows:-

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 2 of 2: BackoffCriteriaDAO_Impl(#2).reset(eq(continuation {}))). Only one matching call to BackoffCriteriaDAO_Impl(#2)/reset(Continuation) happened, but arguments are not matching:
[0]: argument: continuation {}, matcher: eq(continuation {}), result: -
```

My dao reset() method resembles this:-

```
@Transaction
suspend fun reset() {
    delete()
    insert(BackoffCriteriaDO(THE_BACKOFF_CRITERIA_ID, BACKOFF_CRITERIA_MILLISECOND_DELAY, BACKOFF_CRITERIA_MAX_RETRY_COUNT))
}
```

Why am I seeing this `java.lang.AssertionError`?
How do I `coVerify` that suspend functions have been called?

**UPDATE**

I believe the issue is caused by the fact I am using Room database.
My dao interface method `reset()` is implemented by room generated code as

```
 @Override
  public Object reset(final Continuation<? super Unit> p0) {
    return RoomDatabaseKt.withTransaction(__db, new Function1<Continuation<? super Unit>, Object>() {
      @Override
      public Object invoke(Continuation<? super Unit> __cont) {
        return BackoffCriteriaDAO.DefaultImpls.reset(BackoffCriteriaDAO_Impl.this, __cont);
      }
    }, p0);
  }
```

which means the coVerify{} is matching this function and not my interface version.

Is it possible to match this generated version of `public Object reset(final Continuation<? super Unit> p0)`?

Is this a more basic issue with mockk that it cannot mockk java classes?
Or Java implementations of Kotlin interfaces?

**UPDATE 2**

When my Room DAO functions are not suspend then Mockk works as required

using these dummy functions in my DAO:-

```
@Transaction
fun experimentation() {
    experiment()
}

@Transaction
fun experiment() {
    experimental()
}

@Query("DELETE from backoff_criteria")
fun experimental()
```

My test passes

```
@Test
fun experimentation() = runBlocking {
    val actual = myRoomDatabase.backoffCriteriaDAO()
    val dao = spyk(actual)

    dao.experimentation()

    verify { dao.experiment() }
}
```

When I change my dummy functions as follows the test still passes

```
@Transaction
suspend fun experimentation() {
    experiment()
}

@Transaction
fun experiment() {
    experimental()
}

@Query("DELETE from backoff_criteria")
fun experimental()
```

However when I change my dummy functions as follows the test throws an exception

```
@Transaction
suspend fun experimentation() {
    experiment()
}

@Transaction
suspend fun experiment() {
    experimental()
}

@Query("DELETE from backoff_criteria")
fun experimental()
```

The failing tests resembles this:-

```
@Test
fun experimentation() = runBlocking {
    val actual = myRoomDatabase.backoffCriteriaDAO()
    val dao = spyk(actual)

    dao.experimentation()

    coVerify { dao.experiment() }

}
```

The exception is

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 1: BackoffCriteriaDAO_Impl(#2).experiment(eq(continuation {}))). Only one matching call to BackoffCriteriaDAO_Impl(#2)/experiment(Continuation) happened, but arguments are not matching:
[0]: argument: continuation {}, matcher: eq(continuation {}), result: -
```

Comment: Just an idea, you are calling `dao.delete()` before verify. But the method, which you are verifying `dao.reset()` has also `insert(...)` inside its body. From the error, it looks to me, that `insert(...)` is never called, therefore your `coVerify` fails.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my issue. I believe my problem (from the AssertionError) is that as my reset() function is a suspend function a continuation function arg is added which means it doesnt match with the no Args method I have placed in the coVerify{} block. Is it possible to match suspend functions using mockk/spyk?

Answer (score 2):

There might be nothing wrong with `spy` but the asynchronous nature of the transaction function you are invoking.

To test with suspending functions with scope you might need to use

`launch` builder and advance time until idle, or for a time period for testing the progress, like it's done with RxJava counter parts.

I had the same issue with MockWebServer, here you can check out the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62161708/suspending-function-test-with-mockwebserver).

```
  launch {
         dao.delete()
    }

    advanceUntilIdle()
```

And use Coroutine rule with tests to have same scope for each operation.

```
class TestCoroutineRule : TestRule {

    private val testCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

    val testCoroutineScope = TestCoroutineScope(testCoroutineDispatcher)

    override fun apply(base: Statement, description: Description?) = object : Statement() {

        @Throws(Throwable::class)
        override fun evaluate() {

            Dispatchers.setMain(testCoroutineDispatcher)

            base.evaluate()

            Dispatchers.resetMain()
            try {
                testCoroutineScope.cleanupTestCoroutines()
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    fun runBlockingTest(block: suspend TestCoroutineScope.() -> Unit) =
        testCoroutineScope.runBlockingTest { block() }

}
```

You can use rule as below

```
 testCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest {

           dao.delete()

           advanceUntilIdle()
           
            coVerify {
                myRoomDatabase.backoffCriteriaDAO()
                dao.reset()
            }

        }
```

Also you can try putting dao.delete() in `launch`. In some tests it did not work without launch while some other work without it and even some of them are flakky with everything i tried. There are some issues with coroutines-test to be solved.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61730593/coroutines-test-exception-is-not-handled-with-neither-testcoroutinedispatcher-no) you can check how it's done and there are some issues with test-coroutines, you can check out my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61725412/testing-coroutines-runblockingtest-time).

I created a [playground](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Unit-Test-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial6-1Coroutines-Tests/src/test/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial6_1coroutines_tests/Test1Coroutines.kt) to test coroutines, it might helpful and you can test out the issues with coroutines, and [another one](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/CoroutinesAndFlowTutorials/tree/master/Tutorial1-1CoroutinesBasics/src/test/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1coroutinesbasics) with mockK and coroutines tests.